# Cannot get a simple TFRecord reader to work

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

I am trying to get a very simple TFRecord reader to work, but to no avail. (I can get the writer to work just fine).

From [this github repo](https://github.com/jkschin/tf_code/tree/master/TFRecords%20Example), there is a `reader.py` file, and it looks like so:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time
from PIL import Image

def read_and_decode(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
    features = tf.parse_single_example(
            serialized_example,
            # Defaults are not specified since both keys are required.
            features={
                    'height':tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
                    'image_raw': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
                    'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
            })
    image = tf.decode_raw(features['image_raw'], tf.uint8)
    image = tf.reshape(image,[478, 717, 3])
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32) * (1. / 255) - 0.5
    label = tf.cast(features['label'], tf.int32)
    return image


'''
Pointers:   Remember to run init_op
            tf.reshape may not be the ideal way.
'''
def run():
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(["sample.tfrecords"],num_epochs=1)
        images = read_and_decode(filename_queue)
        image_shape = tf.shape(images)
        init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(init_op)
            coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
            threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
            img = sess.run([images])
            coord.request_stop()
            coord.join(threads)
run()
```

The problem is that when I run it, I get the following error:

[image]

So, I have been banging my head on this for the last day. I am not sure what to do, or even why it does not work. It seems like a simple enough example that should have no issue. I am using TF010.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the newer version of TensorFlow:

> `tf.initialize_all_variables()` is deprecated.

They mention that you have to use:

> `tf.global_variables_initializer()`

This doesn't solve the problem. If we look at the newer API of `tf.train.string_input_producer()`, it mentions that num_epochs will be created as a local variable. What is happening here is that there is nothing in the queue for it to read, hence it says requested 1 current 0. Just add this:

> `tf.local_variables_initializer()`

I have pushed the update.

Comment: I am curious, what version of TF were you using when you wrote this example repo originally?

Comment: First commit was in March 2016. Probably 0.7.0 to 0.8.0 if you refer to the release history https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases?after=v0.10.0rc0.

Comment: Since I am somewhat new to TensorFlow, let me ask you, what made you suspect that it is an issue with the tf.initialize_all_variables() from the cryptic error message?

Comment: It requested 1 but it's 0. So I suspected that nothing is in the queue in the first place. If you actually remove num_epochs, it works without any errors. That's when I decided to look deeper into the API and realized this change. Hence, I added that initializer.

Comment: @mrry would it be a good idea for TF to throw "uninitialized local variable" so these situations won't occur?

Comment: @jkschin It's a sensible suggestion, although the implementation would be a little tricky (the place where the error is thrown doesn't know whether the variable is local, global, or something else). This does seem like a usability issue worth solving, so please feel free to open a GitHub issue with the feature request!

Comment: @mrry I seem to have the worst luck with TF. I set out on Tuesday to try and understand TFRecords, and it is now Friday that I have been able to finally get what should have been a simple boiler plate TFRecord to run on my machine. The "all" in tf.initialize_all_variables() not really meaning all certainly didn't help. :-/ I must say that while I think TF is great and I have much to learn... it sometimes seems like the documentation is just... lacking or misleading. Or maybe I have way more to learn. Or both. :)

Comment: @jkschin I finally got everything to run! I had to install TF012 on my machine and that was an adventure because of CUDA. ><. At any rate thanks again for your help!! I think I kind of understand it somewhat better now.

Comment: @Learnaholic well "all" is deprecated so yeah just take some time to read the APIs.

Comment: @jkschin Im new to TF, but is there a way to know ahead of time what is specific commands are deprecated in a certain TF version? I think I would have tried to in any case, but the error message isn't that clear.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may as well be not with TFRecords, but with string_input_producer using LOCAL_VARIABLES collection when num_epochs is set. See [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1045).

The op `tf.initialize_all_variables()` is not initializing **all** variables, as it name suggests. As a quick fix, use the following:

`init_op = tf.group(tf.initialize_all_variables(), tf.initialize_local_variables())`

, but consider going to Tensorflow r0.12, where this op is deprecated in favor of `tf.global_variables_initializer` and `tf.local_variables_initializer`

Comment: Since I am somewhat new to TensorFlow, let me ask you, what made you suspect that it is an issue with the tf.initialize_all_variables() from the cryptic error message?

Comment: I fell into this trap a while ago myself. In my case the message was less cryptic and was about uninitialized variables, so after some googling, I found the discussion on github that I've linked in the original answer.

Comment: Interesting discussion on the link you provided - and yes, the "tf.initialize_all_variables" is extremely misleading in this case! (re: "all")